# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have apple and pears - both have an `isDecayed` attribute:

```
interface Apple {
    color: string;
    isDecayed: boolean;
}

interface Pear {
    weight: number;
    isDecayed: boolean;
}
```

And both types can be in my fruit basket (multiple times):

```
interface FruitBasket {
   apples: Apple[];
   pears: Pear[];
}
```

Let's assume for now my basket is empty:

```
const fruitBasket: FruitBasket = { apples: [], pears: [] };
```

Now we take randomly one kind out of the basket:

```
const key: keyof FruitBasket = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'apples': 'pears'; 
const fruits = fruitBasket[key];
```

And of course nobody likes decayed fruits so we pick only the fresh ones:

```
const freshFruits = fruits.filter((fruit) => !fruit.isDecayed);
```

Unfortunately Typescript tells me:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: Apple, index: number, array: Apple[]) => any, thisArg?: any) => Apple[]) | ...' has no compatible call signatures.

What's wrong here - is it just that Typescript doesn't like fresh fruits or is this a Typescript bug?

You can try it yourself in the official [Typescript Repl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Apple%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isDecayed%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Pear%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isDecayed%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FruitBasket%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20apples%3A%20Apple%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pears%3A%20Pear%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fruitBasket%3A%20FruitBasket%20%3D%20%7B%20apples%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20pears%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20key%3A%20keyof%20FruitBasket%20%3D%20Math.random()%20%3E%200.5%20%3F%20'apples'%3A%20'pears'%3B%20%0D%0Aconst%20fruits%20%3D%20fruitBasket%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20freshFruits%20%3D%20fruits.filter((fruit)%20%3D%3E%20!fruit.isDecayed)%3B).

Comment: Having tried google https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7960

Comment: Any reason you can't extend a generic `Fruit` interface with the `isDecayed` property and then declare fruits to be of type `Fruit[]`?

Comment: strange...there is no error if you explicitly set the `key` to `string` i.e `const key: string = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'apples': 'pears';`

Comment: ^ happens because without an explicit index signature, the return type will be `any` which circumvents the issue.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

TypeScript supports structural typing (also called duck typing), meaning that [types are compatible when they share the same members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). Your problem is that `Apple` and `Pear` don't share all their members, which means that they are not compatible. They are however compatible to another type that has only the `isDecayed: boolean` member. Because of structural typing, you don' need to inherit `Apple` and `Pear` from such an interface.

There are different ways to assign such a compatible type:

**Assign type during variable declaration**

This statement is implicitly typed to `Apple[] | Pear[]`:

```
const fruits = fruitBasket[key];
```

You can simply use a compatible type explicitly in in your variable declaration:

```
const fruits: { isDecayed: boolean }[] = fruitBasket[key];
```

For additional reusability, you can also define the type first and then use it in your declaration (note that the `Apple` and `Pear` interfaces don't need to be changed):

```
type Fruit = { isDecayed: boolean };
const fruits: Fruit[] = fruitBasket[key];
```

**Cast to compatible type for the operation**

The problem with the given solution is that it changes the type of the `fruits` variable. This might not be what you want. To avoid this, you can narrow the array down to a compatible type before the operation and then set the type back to the same type as `fruits`:

```
const fruits: fruitBasket[key];
const freshFruits = (fruits as { isDecayed: boolean }[]).filter(fruit => !fruit.isDecayed) as typeof fruits;
```

Or with the reusable `Fruit` type:

```
type Fruit = { isDecayed: boolean };
const fruits: fruitBasket[key];
const freshFruits = (fruits as Fruit[]).filter(fruit => !fruit.isDecayed) as typeof fruits;
```

The advantage of this solution is that both, `fruits` and `freshFruits` will be of type `Apple[] | Pear[]`.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7960) originally linked by @peter in the comments:

```
const freshFruits = (fruits as (Apple | Pear)[]).filter((fruit: (Apple | Pear)) => !fruit.isDecayed);
```

Comment: I don't have an mixed array of Apple and Pears but an array of Apples or an array of Pears.

Comment: Same reason why I use Typescript: To structure my code, that I or a third-person gets a better understanding what the code is doing and with what the code is dealing with. And a mixed array of Apples and Pears isn't what ever will be in that array. So why should I define it as a mixed array?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the statement that the array will either contain Apples or Pears isn't false it's just not describing the entire truth.

Comment: You're absolutly right. But if I have the opportunity to describe it more detailed, I want to use that method and this is the point I don't get why Typescript is handling the more detailed one as an error.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps create a shared `Fruit` interface that provides isDecayed. `fruits` is now of type `Fruit[]` so the type can be explicit. Like this:

```
interface Fruit {
    isDecayed: boolean;
}

interface Apple extends Fruit {
    color: string;
}

interface Pear extends Fruit {
    weight: number;
}

interface FruitBasket {
    apples: Apple[];
    pears: Pear[];
}


const fruitBasket: FruitBasket = { apples: [], pears: [] };
const key: keyof FruitBasket = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'apples': 'pears'; 
const fruits: Fruit[] = fruitBasket[key];

const freshFruits = fruits.filter((fruit) => !fruit.isDecayed);
```

Comment: Thanks - That's the workaround I have used in the meantime but it still feels more like a hack than a real solution to me. Is this the only way?

Comment: This happens all the time. Your `FruitBasket` could be just an array of `Fruit`s too

Answer (score -6):

I had the same issue with numeral, a JS library. The fix was to install the typings again with this command:

```
npm install --save @types/numeral
```