# Typescript type lacks call of signature in abstract class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a custom validator class in Typescript :

```
abstract class ValidatorBase<T>
{
    protected abstract Rules: Rule[];

    public Validate(t: T): string[]
    {
        return this.Rules.filter(rule => rule.Test(t)).map(rule => rule.ErrorMsg);
    }
}

export class Rule 
{
    public Test: Map<any, boolean>;
    public ErrorMsg: string;
}
```

However, "rule.Test(t)" gives me a compiler error :

> "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   'Map`<any, boolean`>' has no compatible call signatures."

I have seen there a few questions regarding this issue on this forum already, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427393/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature):

But my problem seems different, since there are no interfaces or inheriting involved.

Whats the reason behind this error? Is it possible to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rule.Test` is `Map`, it is not a function.

Do you mean `rule.Test.get(t)`?

See the definition of `Map`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Yes, which is an instance of `Map`. It is not a function.

Comment: Oh yeah! Im so used to {get; set;} from C#. Thanks! That worked