# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature ... has no compatible call signatures

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

i get an error

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature ... has no compatible call signatures.
```

on one of my methods and i cant figure out how to fix it.
i have seen this link [cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427393/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature)

and 2 more but still didn`t mange to figure it out

type declaration :

```js
type ProcessMethods = "execute" | "execSpawn"

interface IDeferedCmd {
    type: ProcessMethods,
    cmd: string,
    name: string,
    resolve: IResolveFn,
    reject: IRejectFn,
    args?: Array<string>,
    options?: object


}
```

in my class i have 2 static methods that looks like this

```js
static execute({cmd, name}: { cmd: string, name: string }): Promise<{
        stdout: string;
        stderr: string;
    }>

static execSpawn({cmd, name, args , options }: { cmd: string, name: string, args: Array<string>, options: object }): Promise<NodeJS.ReadableStream>
```

and a third method in witch the error is thrown from try to call them dynamicly

```js
if (typeof firstDeferedCmd == "object" && ( firstDeferedCmd.type === "execute" || firstDeferedCmd.type === "execSpawn" )) {
                ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type](firstDeferedCmd); // this line throw the error
}
```

and the error it self

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(({ cmd, name }: { cmd: string; name: string; }) => Promise<{}>) | (({ cmd, name, args, options }...' has no compatible call signatures.
>   ProcessPoolExecutorfirstDeferedCmd.type;
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the two functions have different signatures so the result of the indexing operation will be a union of the two signatures which by definition will not be callable.

You can use the `Function` methods `call` or `apply` which are accessible (since they are common to both signatures in the union) to call the function, with the disadvantage of losing all type safety:

```
if (typeof firstDeferedCmd == "object" && ( firstDeferedCmd.type === "execute" || firstDeferedCmd.type === "execSpawn" )) {
    ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type].call(ProcessPoolExecutor, firstDeferedCmd);
}
```

You can always just use an assertion to make the union callable, but this is not any safer then `call`:

```
if (typeof firstDeferedCmd == "object" && ( firstDeferedCmd.type === "execute" || firstDeferedCmd.type === "execSpawn" )) {
    (ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type] as (cmd: IDeferedCmd) => Promise<{stdout: string;stderr: string;}> | Promise<NodeJS.ReadableStream>)(firstDeferedCmd);
}
```

You could also use two checks to sperate out the two different signatures, and this actually exposes an issue with your current design:

```
function fn(firstDeferedCmd : IDeferedCmd){
    if (typeof firstDeferedCmd == "object") {
        if(firstDeferedCmd.type === "execute") {
            return ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type](firstDeferedCmd);
        }
        if(firstDeferedCmd.type === "execSpawn") {
            if(firstDeferedCmd.args){
                return ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type](firstDeferedCmd);  // error since there is no requirement if execSpawn is specified to also specify args
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can fix this by changing the definition of the `IDeferedCmd`:

```
type IDeferedCmd = {
    type: "execute",
    cmd: string,
    name: string,
} | {
    type: "execSpawn",
    cmd: string,
    name: string,
    resolve: IResolveFn,
    reject: IRejectFn,
    args: Array<string>,
    options: object


}
function fn(firstDeferedCmd : IDeferedCmd){
    if (typeof firstDeferedCmd == "object") {
        if(firstDeferedCmd.type === "execute") {
            return ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type](firstDeferedCmd);
        }
        if(firstDeferedCmd.type === "execSpawn") {
            if(firstDeferedCmd.args){
                return ProcessPoolExecutor[firstDeferedCmd.type](firstDeferedCmd);  // ok now
            }
        }
    }
}
```