# Typescript conflict type enum number and number in NestJS/ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, next.js

I would add types to my NestJS server.

I have written a controller (route for Express lovers) then tried to specify the type for params:

```
public async getAllMessages(
  @Query('startDate', ValidateDate) startDate: string,
  @Query('endDate', ValidateDate) endDate: string,
  @Res() res: Response,
): Promise<string> {
  const data = await this.crudService.getPeriodicMessages(startDate, endDate);
  return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(data);
}
```

Here I've added the type `Response` to `res`, since I get this error message in `res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(data)`.

**ERROR**  : `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.`.

I have checked the Response type has `status` member of type `number` and `HttpStatus.OK` is of type `enum number` also, so how can I convert it to `number`?

I have also read [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427393/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature/42487130) but couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: What about `res.status(HttpStatus.OK as number)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example there is no need to inject the response object with `@Res()`.

You can just do the following, nest will handle the response automatically. The http status code will always be 200 by default (201 for POST).

```
public async getAllMessages(@Query('startDate', ValidateDate) startDate: string,
                            @Query('endDate', ValidateDate) endDate: string): Promise<string> {
  return this.crudService.getPeriodicMessages(startDate, endDate);
}
```

You only need to inject the response object for special cases, like setting the response code dynamically.