# Structural typing workaround doesn't work

Tags: typescript

I have a function that performs some operations on different types of arrays. The arrays that the function can receive have a common property (i.e. `selected`). I understand that Typescript uses structural typing and so I wouldn't be able to type like:

```
interface typeA {
    propOne: string
    selected: boolean
}

interface typeB {
    propTwo: string
    propThree: string
    selected: boolean
}


function sampleFn(): void {
    allSelected = someArray.every((item: typeA | typeB) => item.selected);
}
```

I took a look at a similar SO question ([Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427393/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature/42487130)) and have changed it to:

```
function sampleFn(): void {
    type select = {selected: boolean};
    arr = someArray.every((item: select) => item.selected);
 }
```

I'm still getting a `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature` error. What am I missing?

Comment: Please give a [mre] - your example fail because `arr`, `allSelected` and `someArray` aren't defined.

Comment: If I'm reading the other question right, you most likely need to have `someArray` be `(typeA | typeB)[]` instead of `typeA[] | typeB[]`